# Can I run a minimalist web-server on my router without rewriting the firmware with DD-WRT?

Tags: linux, router, webserver, dd-wrt, httpd

I read [this article on Nezzen.net](http://nezzen.net/2007/10/15/running-a-web-server-on-a-home-router/) that says that you can make a web-server on your router providing that you rewrite its firmware with a free DD-WRT, Tomato, or equivalent.

Leaving apart the fact there is no DD-WRT available for my router, I don't know if I would change the firmware.

Is it possible to make `httpd` run as a minimalist webserver without changing the firmware? This might mean that I need to have a file system in the RAM memory. I try to `cat something >file` I see the filesystem is obviously read-only, but it should have some writable parts, somewhere it needs to keep its settings!

If I connect with telnet to the router I see it already has in `bin` folder:  `httpd` and `ftpd`, `ftp` binaries.

Also in `/home/httpd/web/` has some html files but the filesystem is read-only.

The router is Sitecom WLM 2501.

Comment: From experience, **yes it is possible**, but be aware that the default firmware also has a web server running on port 80 (to allow you to connect to the router itself via web browser).  You'll need to run your server on an alternate port, or modify the one DD-WRT uses by default.

Comment: I don't use DD-WRT

Comment: The answer to this question is highly model specific, and you have not provided the model of your router.

Comment: One option that can work on many routers is to forward port 80 (web) to a web server running internally. This does not answer your question, as you still need another system to run the web server on, but it may accomplish your purpose.

Comment: @kmarsh The router is Sitecom WLM 2501.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is very unlikely you'll be able to modify the settings on the router sufficiently to work around its existing firmware.