# Web-server with power consumption below 20 W?

Tags: power, webserver, lamp

There are some workarounds to do this like making a [router into an webserver](https://superuser.com/questions/464073/can-i-run-a-minimalist-web-server-on-my-router-without-rewriting-the-firmware-wi) or [making a remote storage device into a LAMP machine.](https://superuser.com/questions/464073/can-i-run-a-minimalist-web-server-on-my-router-without-rewriting-the-firmware-wi) or [even your smartphone into a webserver](http://lifehacker.com/5920173/use-your-android-phone-as-a-full-fledged-web-server).

Am I missing something, are there any other ways to do this?

Comment: What about a NAS like those from Synology or QNAP? they both web servers with PHP.

Comment: @MattH I think those would qualify too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi is a credit-card sized computer that plugs into your TV and a keyboard. It’s a capable little PC which can be used for many of the things that your desktop PC does, like spreadsheets, word-processing and games. It also plays high-definition video. We want to see it being used by kids all over the world to learn programming.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/

[image]
[image]

Comment: Also there are starting to apear some [LAMP distributions too](http://www.raspberrypioneer.com/2012/06/12/raspberry-pi-project-3-lampi-a-raspberry-pi-based-lamp-server/) and with an WiFi dongle can have also the second internet connection. ***With under 5 W consumption*** I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Since Raspberri's PI release, there has been several others, I would recommend doing your research and finding the best solution. However, this is just one of many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

As kobaltz suggests, Raspberry Pi is a good possibility.  However, if for whatever reason you need an x86 based solution or something with a bit more RAM and CPU power you can also meet your power target using an off-the-shelf Intel Atom or AMD Brazos build.

I put together an [Atom D510 server box](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/496) awhile ago, and I've got 4 web server instances running on it at the moment (2x Apache httpd, 2x Apache Tomcat) as well as a SVN server.  That's probably well beyond what could be done with a single Raspberry Pi instance, mostly due to memory requirements.

I've had no issues with this system at all in terms of stability/reliability (it's been running 24/7 for months now), and the power consumption is just over 20W at full load (though the only time I've ever seen it at full load was when I was benchmarking for the purposes of measuring power-consumption at full load).

So you've got a couple of different options.